reading with multiple threads using ifstream
Need to speed up file reading, so decided to use multithreading
I have a very simple programm for it:
int main()
{
    std::string mPath = "input.txt";
    std::ifstream in_1(mPath, std::ifstream::ate | std::ifstream::binary);
    std::streampos size = in_1.tellg();
    in_1.close();
    std::streampos half = size / 2;


    auto lambd = [&mPath](std::streampos start, std::streampos end)
        {
            auto clock_start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            std::string word;
            std::ifstream fstream(mPath);
            fstream.seekg(start);
            auto counter = start;

            std::string rangeStr = std::to_string(start) + ' ' + std::to_string(end);

            while ((counter < end) && (fstream >> word))
            {
                counter += word.length() + 1;
                //some usefull work with data, was commented  during tests

            }
            auto clock_now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            float currentTime = float(std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::microseconds> (clock_now - clock_start).count());
            std::cout << "\nThread Elapsed Time:(" << rangeStr << ") " << currentTime / 1000000 << " S" << std::endl;
        };

    lambd(0, size);
    lambd(0, half);
    lambd(half, size);

    std::thread th_1(lambd, 0, half);
    std::thread th_2(lambd, half, size);

    th_1.join();
    th_2.join();
}

And I have got very strange output(Windows 11, visual studio 2022):
Thread Elapsed Time:(0 1520000000) 18.9158 S
Thread Elapsed Time:(0 760000000) 9.36048 S
Thread Elapsed Time:(760000000 1520000000) 9.3542 S
Thread Elapsed Time:(0 760000000) 38.2231 S
Thread Elapsed Time:(760000000 1520000000) 38.3247 S
I should use only c++ library, so could not use nmap.
Could I ask you for supprt ? Why does it happen, that whe I'm using multithreading - I have such big gap? Does it mean the ifstream use same data stream if file is the same ? Maybe I could avoid it somehow? I don't want to use C-style reading.
UPDATED TEXT BELOW:
thank you very much for answers.Makar Biziukin gave proposals, which sounds reasonable
But in general - don't understand why does the same code written in 'C-style' works better. And it was main motivation to ask question.
It's interresting for me, why does behavior of ifstream is differ so much from fopen and fcanf.
Code has been rewritten one-to-one using c-style.
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::string path = "input.txt";
    FILE* fp = fopen(path.c_str(), "r");
    char str[100];
    std::fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); // seek to end
    std::size_t filesize = std::ftell(fp);
    std::size_t half = filesize / 2;
    std::fseek(fp, half, SEEK_SET);
    fscanf(fp, "%s", str);
    half = std::ftell(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\n\n!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n\n";
        auto lamdb = [&path](size_t start, size_t end)
            {
                auto clock_start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
                char str[100];
                FILE* fp = fopen(path.c_str(), "r");
                std::fseek(fp, start, SEEK_SET);

                std::string rangeStr = std::to_string(start) + ' ' + std::to_string(end);

                while ((start < end) && (fscanf(fp, "%s", str) != EOF))
                {
                    start += strlen(str) + 1;
                    //some usefull work with data, was commented  during tests
                }
                auto clock_now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
                float currentTime = float(std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::microseconds> (clock_now - clock_start).count());
                std::cout << "\nThread Elapsed Time:(" << rangeStr << ") " << currentTime / 1000000 << " S" << std::endl;

                fclose(fp);
            };
        lamdb(0, filesize);
        lamdb(0, half);
        lamdb(half, filesize);

        std::thread th_1(lamdb, 0, half);
        std::thread th_2(lamdb, half, filesize);

        th_1.join();
        th_2.join();
    }

    return 0;    
}

one of the outputs(all output results are near to each other):
Thread Elapsed Time:(0 1520000000) 21.7994 S
Thread Elapsed Time:(0 760000007) 10.7144 S
Thread Elapsed Time:(760000007 1520000000) 10.8991 S
Thread Elapsed Time:(760000007 1520000000) 12.6544 S
Thread Elapsed Time:(0 760000007) 13.3838 S

Note: Multithreaded reading is usually a waste of time. Unless you have groovy hardware there's only one channel to the hard disk, so the multiple threads just waste time fighting over that channel. There are ways around this, but you have to walk away from the likes of standard file streams.

I don't want to use C-style reading Why? You're using multithreading because you want to speed things up. Using mmap on the file is arguably the fastest way to do things (with some pointers and string functions such as strchr, etc). Or, using pread. With streams, you have an extra layer of buffering. And, AFAIK, each stream has its own buffering. Okay, unless you need absolute speed. As to only c++ library, is this a H/W assignment?

@buggizhuk The C++ streams have extra synchronization built in to prevent screw-ups when using C and C++ style IO simultaneously. you can turn that off with sync_with_stdio. IO streams are also heavier than stdio, and you really see that extra weight if you don't allow the compiler to optimize. General note: time measurements of unoptimized code are mostly meaningless in C++ because the Standard library counts on the compiler eliminating a lot of boilerplate.

The performance degradation you're seeing is due to several factors:
1.  Disk I/O Contention: Multiple threads reading from the same physical disk can cause the disk head to jump back and forth, resulting in worse performance than sequential reading.
2.  File System Buffering: Windows file system maintains buffers, and concurrent access can lead to buffer thrashing.
Try this version:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>

class BufferedFileReader {
private:
    std::vector<char> buffer;
    size_t position = 0;

public:
    BufferedFileReader(const std::string& path, std::streampos start, std::streampos size) {
        std::ifstream file(path, std::ios::binary);
        if (!file) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Cannot open file");
        }

        buffer.resize(size);
        file.seekg(start);
        file.read(buffer.data(), size);
    }

    bool getNextWord(std::string& word) {
        word.clear();
        // Skip whitespace
        while (position < buffer.size() && std::isspace(buffer[position])) {
            position++;
        }

        if (position >= buffer.size()) {
            return false;
        }

        // Read word
        while (position < buffer.size() && !std::isspace(buffer[position])) {
            word += buffer[position++];
        }

        return !word.empty();
    }
};

void processFileChunk(const std::string& path, std::streampos start, std::streampos size) {
    auto clock_start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    
    try {
        BufferedFileReader reader(path, start, size);
        std::string word;
        size_t wordCount = 0;

        while (reader.getNextWord(word)) {
            // Process word here
            wordCount++;
        }

        auto clock_now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        float currentTime = float(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(clock_now - clock_start).count());
        std::cout << "Thread Elapsed Time:(" << start << " " << (start + size) 
                 << ") " << currentTime / 1000000 << "s, Words: " << wordCount << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string mPath = "input.txt";
    
    // Get file size
    std::ifstream file(mPath, std::ifstream::ate | std::ifstream::binary);
    if (!file) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot open file" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    
    std::streampos totalSize = file.tellg();
    file.close();

    // Calculate chunk sizes
    const int numThreads = 4; // You can adjust this
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::streampos chunkSize = totalSize / numThreads;

    // First test sequential reading
    std::cout << "Sequential reading:" << std::endl;
    processFileChunk(mPath, 0, totalSize);

    // Now test parallel reading
    std::cout << "\nParallel reading:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        std::streampos start = i * chunkSize;
        std::streampos size = (i == numThreads - 1) ? (totalSize - start) : chunkSize;
        threads.emplace_back(processFileChunk, mPath, start, size);
    }

    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }

    return 0;
}


Pushing Remy's answer here as a superior way to suck a file into a vector of bytes. tellg is only guaranteed to give you a value that can be used to return to a point in a stream. Using it to get the size of a file is a trick that only falls into the "Usually Works" category. You don't get enough of an advantage from it to be worth the mindfreak when it doesn't work. I'd suck the file into the buffered reader and call a new method in the reader returns the vector's size.

You need to protect getNextWord from concurrent access. Currently you could have multiple threads inside the function both incrementing position and producing complete gibberish. You cannot simply protect position; you need to protect the entire transaction to ensure that each caller gets exactly one word. A mutex should work well here, but not that the threads will now waste time fighting over the mutex.

If the the Asker can cleanly partition the buffer they'll never run into this problem. Each thread will never mess with another thread's partition, but that requires that the partitions never split up a word. Could be a really tricky thing to ensure.

thank you very much for answer and comments. Interesting solutio, which might be accepted in my case. But that's interesting for me - why I have differences, using fstream and fscanf

@buggizhuk be very careful using this answer directly as written. The lack of thread synchronization means it is very fast and very broken. The concept is good, but the implementation is flawed.
